# Setting Alarm Manager in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am following Android developers documentation and some other tuts to create an Alarm manager which fires and wakes up the CPU at 4pm everyday, following is my code:

```
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    BroadcastReceiver br;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}


public void setup() {
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Invoke the service here Put the wake lock and initiate bind service

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.testrtc") );
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.testrtc"),
            0 );
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

However I dont get any errors, but the alarm (Toast message) wont fire.

**EDIT** from the developer docs:

RTC examples

Here are some examples of using RTC_WAKEUP.

Wake up the device to fire the alarm at approximately 2:00 p.m., and repeat once a day at the same time:

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

This one for set Repeating, says that if I want my alarm to fire at 8:30 and then repeat after each 20 minutes, however I just want to fire my alarm at a specific time but I dont want to repeat it.

Wake up the device to fire the alarm at precisely 8:30 a.m., and every 20 minutes thereafter:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: you want to fire alarm on exact time then why are you using `setInexactRepeating` ? just use `setRepeating` and you are done.simple.

Comment: While I understand that what you are saying makes sense, but however the developer docs seem to be confusing me. Refer to the edit part in my Question above.

Comment: I've posted answer with solution code and explanation about why you should not use `setInexactRepeating`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Decide how precise your alarm needs to be**

Choosing the alarm type is often the first step in creating an alarm. A further distinction is how precise you need your alarm to be. For most apps, `setInexactRepeating()` is the right choice. When you use this method, **Android synchronizes multiple inexact repeating alarms and fires them at the same time**. This reduces the drain on the battery.

For the rare app that has rigid time requirements like yours, the alarm needs to fire **precisely** at 4:00 p.m. everyday then use **`setRepeating()`**.

Reference: [Decide how precise your alarm needs to be](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)

**`Solution :`**

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 4:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000*60*60*24, alarmIntent);
```

**Edited Testing :** `(Fire alarm at every 10seconds)`

```
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
        1000*10, alarmIntent);
```

**Conclusion :**

`setup()` method was not called before dealing with alarms.

---

### Update for API 19+

setRepeating is inexact when targeting api level 19 or higher. For exact repating you can now use `setExact()` and manage repeating yourself.

reference: [AlarmManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: @user2822178: it will display at 4pm only.kindly change the time for testing purpose.

Comment: Yes I changed the time too, set it at 17:15 IST

Comment: @user2822178: I've added test case,try it.

Comment: Not firing even after ten second interval. (Pulls my hair)

Comment: @user2822178: calm down and have faith ;-) . try edited testing code,let me know if it works for you

Comment: Tried the above, dont function;

Comment: @user2822178: I'm pretty sure that problem is not with alarm manager,you are messing up somewhere else.because these codes are working for my existing apps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45640/discussion-between-user2822178-and-mehul-joisar)

Comment: update please your answer, setRepeating behavior changed with API 19

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `setInexactRepeating()` I suggest you to use `setRepeating()`

from the docs,

**setInexactRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)**

- Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour.

**setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)**

- Schedule a repeating alarm.

Comment: Scheduling a repeating alarm is for intervals after boot completion I think? Also if it has to be repeated after some interval http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: So do you want to persist the Alarm even after booting device ?

Comment: Yes I want to persist the alarm, that I intend to do after invoking a boot complete listener. However for that first the alarm should function properly. Also my concern is that Do I have to explicitly get a wake lock or will the RTC wake up do that for me?

Comment: No my question is not about booting and persisting the Alarm, instead my question is that my alarm dont fire. `Without considering Boot`

Comment: so it is not firing for a single time ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45631/discussion-between-vigbyor-and-user2822178)

Comment: No I am testing on MaxSDK = 18 and I am using JellyBean on the test device.

Comment: @Tobor while you are right at your side, but still OP hasnt mentioned that he/she has is on Kitkat version or not.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is quite clear:

[public void setInexactRepeating (...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

> triggerAtMillis   time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go
>   off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type). This
>   is inexact: the alarm will not fire before this time, but there may be
>   a delay of almost an entire alarm interval before the first invocation
>   of the alarm.

so to my understanding **but there may be a delay of almost an entire alarm interval** means you may have one day delay, because u use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.

Comment: And how do I overcome that? I cannot afford to invoke this alarm a day after!

Comment: you might change to INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, you would at least see if that is the cause of your problem - alarm should fire aproximately in 15minutes.

Comment: The documentation about Alarm Manager is so scarce!!

Answer (score 2):

set minutes and seconds also to calendar ..

```
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 16); // At the hour you wanna fire
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

and use

```
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem (usually is an Huawei issue) and I resolved by enabling the app in the PowerManager or Protected Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a receiver that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(myService);
    }
}
```

In your service, you can put your toast, or try to write a log in a file to be sure that it works. Then, in your activity:

```
       Intent myAlarm = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
       PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, myAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
       AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 4 * 1000 * 60, recurringAlarm);
```

// Alarm every 4 minutes